# Generate a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a `MATLAB` problem to generate a vector like `1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4...`

So `if n = 3`, then return

`[1 2 2 3 3 3]`
And if `n = 5`, then return

`[1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5]`

This is what I came up with:

```
ans=1
for n=2:n
ans=[ans n*ones(1,n)]
end
```

But I'm trying to minimize the code length. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you after better efficiency, or shorter code length? Dont use `ans` , it's a matlab generated variable name.

Comment: If I may point out, as a rule of thumb I think going after code length might not be the best idea. From the 5+ years of programming experience I would recommend going for readability first and then, if needed performance

Answer (score 2):

still a few lines:

```
n = 5;     %number of elements

A(cumsum(0:n)+1) = 1;
B = cumsum(A(1:end-1))
```

returns

```
1   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5
```

Comment: I guess he would like a one that occupies the least computing nodes in matlab....http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/1035-generate-a-vector-like-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4-4-4

Comment: @lennon310 what is a "computing node"? If it's what I think, I count 4, which would be the shortest ;)

Comment: check this out  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/about/cody/#solutionsize   an interesting competition, but it will not be once you get the trick of that

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit, here's my one liner:

```
nonzeros(triu(meshgrid(1:n)))'
```

Comment: ... however, `ones(1,n).'*(1:n)` is much faster than `meshgrid`

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the goal is to get the minimum # of matlab nodes according to `mtree`, for the use in the `Cody` game. see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34754-calculate-size/content/calculateSize.m  and the comments above.

Comment: @ Luis Mendo, in my check `repmat` is faster than meshgrid... compare `f=@() repmat(1:n,n,1);` to  `g=@()meshgrid(1:n)`using timeitm for n=10,100,1000 ...

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5;
A = triu(ones(n,1)*(1:n));
A(A==0) = [];
```

Comment: which is in terms of the ["competetion"](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/1035-generate-a-vector-like-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4-4-4) the shortest (27 nodes), but still much longer than other already submitted solutions ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk I didn't know about these MATLAB solutions competitions.  Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to jkshah's answer, but I would approach it slightly differently,

```
n=5;
M = ones(n,1)*(1:n)
B = M(triu(ones(n))>0)';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one-liner. Unlike solutions based on `triu`, this one doesn't generate extra elements as intermediate results (that doesn't mean it's faster, though):

```
fliplr(cumsum([n full(sparse(ones(1,n-1),cumsum(n:-1:2),-1))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A little 'magic' solution:

```
ceil(sqrt(2*(1:(n^2+n)/2))-0.5)
```

See visualisation:
[image]
This is the plot of function sqrt(2*(1:(n^2+n)/2))-0.5:

```
plot(1:(n^2+n)/2,sqrt(2*(1:(n^2+n)/2))-0.5,'.')
```

where **xticklabels** were changed according the following code:

```
set(gca,'xtick',cumsum(0:n),'xticklabel',0:n)
```

Answer (score 0):

**it is a litle bit longer**

```
function y = your_fcn_name(n)
      N = sum(1:n);w = [] ; 
      for i=1:n
         q(1:i) = i;
         w      = [w q(1:i)];
      end
      y = w;
end
```